# creating new struct in cycle

Tags: c++, struct

I've got problem with declaring the struct in cycle. Here is my code:

```
struct v;

struct e{
    e* next;
    bool choosen;
    v* target;
};

struct v {
    e* start;
    e* end;
    bool choosen;
    int skel; // how many edges in skeleton from this v
    int number;
};

void add(v* v1, e* e1) {
    if(v1->start==0) {
        v1->start=e1;
        v1->end=e1;
    }else{
        v1->end->next=e1;
        v1->end=e1;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
    cin>>t1>>t2;
    e ed={0,false,&b[t2]};
    add(&b[t1], &ed);
}
```

I need in every cycle of the for cycle create new struct e and pass in to the method add. The problem is, that it just redefined the values, but the object struct is the same. So after all there are just pointers to the same struct e. Is there any way how to fix it? Something like new declaration?

EDIT: I've added  the whole code, to be clear what I am doing with the pointers.

Comment: If you really need to, use `new`. Don't forget to `delete` each element later on.

Comment: Your variable `ed` is local inside the loop, once the loop continues or exits, the variable goes out of scope and is destructed, leaving you with an invalid pointer, and leading you to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out the struct `ed` is only valid within the for-loop i.e. it's visibility so if you're lucky you get no crash;

I would suggest using:

```
for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    cin >> t1 >> t2;

    e* ed = new e();
    ed->next = 0x00;
    ed->choosen = false;
    ed->target = &b[t2];

    add(&b[t1], ed);
}
```

instead. Dont forget to delete the elements when they're removed from your container and not needed anymore.

Comment: you are doing the same thing as he is; the difference is the is using a initialization list and you are explicitly assigning values

Comment: @Pandrei Difference between `e ed;` and `e* ed = new e();`??

Comment: sorry missed that; but you do add a memory leak -please edit your answer to fix it.

Comment: @Pandrei: The answer says "don't forget to delete the elements", which will fix the leak. They shouldn't be deleted at this point since they've been passed to `add`. (Although a note about smart pointers might be nice.)

Comment: @Pandrei where's there a memory leak. Since we do not know where he needs the structs (most likely somewhere outside) we may not delete them (thats why I wrote that he does not forget to delete them later on)

Comment: @MikeSeymour the local variable is allocated on the stack, so it should not matter unless the compiler is doing some optimizations; each time you enter the for loop a different object of type ed should be allocated on the stack

Comment: @Pandrei: I've no idea what you mean. The `e` object can't be a local variable since `add` stores a pointer to it to use later - after a local variable will have been destroyed. A solution, as this answer describes, is to dynamically allocate the object, so that it will last as long as it's needed.

Comment: @Robert: each time you call new() you allocate new memory on the heap and you use the same pointer to keep track of it; so if you don't call delete before calling new you have a memory leak. If you call delete outside of the loop you will free only the last allocated object

Comment: @Pandrei I think the `add()` function inserts the struct into a container (list, map, whatever) so he stores the pointers somewhere. So when he dont need the elements anymore, he can go through his container, remove and delete them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: actually that's not true; the function add does take a pointer, but it does not store it, it copies the content of the pointer to some other location; and this happens in the same for iteration. The code should work fine without needing the variable to be allocated on the heap

Comment: @Pandrei: How on earth do you know that without seeing what `add` does? Clearly it doesn't do that, otherwise there would be no problem and the question wouldn't be asked. The question certainly wouldn't say "after all there are just pointers to the same struct e" if there were no pointers being stored.

Comment: @Robert: we're just assuming what add does; if you ask me I wouldn't store the pointers as it's more error prone.

Comment: @Pandrei Why should he pass the address to the struct `add(...,&ed)` to then internally copy the content be derefernce the pointer again with `*ed` that would not realy make sense (in my opinion), so I think it is most likely that he stores the pointer. In addition, as the OP states out: "So after all there are just pointers to the same struct e"

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I was just trying to make a point; we can't really say that the correct solution is unless we know what add is doing. regardless of what it does this piece of code should work fine with the variable allocated on the stack. Though the code might break somewhere else

Comment: @Robert because if you don't pass a pointer to a struct as argument to a function but pass it by value, you copy the content of the struct on the stack - that's why you ALWAYS pass struct variables to functions by pointer.

Comment: @Pandrei: It's quite clear from the description what `add` does, and why it's a problem if `ed` is a local variable. If you have a better solution than dynamic allocation then please write your own answer rather than posting confusing comments to someone else's.

Comment: @MikeSeymour now it becomes clear, because he posted the code to add; when we started debating it was not there.

Comment: @Pandrei after reading discussion I've post it. So far I don't need to use the delete() in for cycle because it is stored in another struct? Is it correct?

Comment: @Pandrei To your statement: "because if you don't pass a pointer to a struct as argument to a function but pass it by value, you copy the content of the struct on the stack - that's why you ALWAYS pass struct variables to functions by pointer." If I really only need the content, then I would use a (probably const) reference

Comment: @Robert: I'm not sure where you are going with this :) the compiler implements pointers and reference variables the same way -> using pointers

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64858/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-creating-new-struct-in-cycle).